# What happens when the ARP cache overflows?

Tags: router, routing, brocade, arp

In at least one implementation there is a hard limit on the capacity of the ARP table. What happens when the ARP cache is full and a packet is offered with a destination (or next-hop) that isn't cached? What happens under the hood, and what is the effect on the service quality?

For example, Brocade NetIron XMR and Brocade MLX routers have a [configurable `ip-arp` system maximum](http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/html_product_manuals/NI_05400a_CFG/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=System_params.05.22.html#1105863). The default value in that case is 8192; the size of a /19 subnet. It is not clear from the documentation whether this is per interface or for the whole router, but for the purpose of this question, we can assume it is per interface.

Few networkers would configure a /19 subnet on an interface on purpose, but that isn't what happened. We were migrating a core router from a Cisco model to a Brocade. One of the many differences between Cisco and Brocade is that Cisco accepts static routes that are defined with both an outbound interface and a next-hop address, but Brocade insists on one or the other. We dropped the next-hop address and kept the interface. Later, we learned the error of our ways, and changed from interface to next-hop address, but everything seemed to be working initially.

```
+----+ iface0    +----+
| R1 |-----------| R2 |---> (10.1.0.0/16 this way)
+----+.1       .2+----+
      10.0.0.0/30
```

Before the migration, R1 was a Cisco, and had the following route.

```
ip route 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 iface0 10.0.0.2
```

After the migration, R1 was a Brocade, and had the following route.

```
ip route 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 iface0
```

R2 is a Cisco router, and Cisco routers perform [proxy ARP](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk361/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094adb.shtml) by default. This is the (mis-)configuration in production that set the stage for what turned out to be an ARP cache overflow.

1. R1 receives a packet destined for the 10.1.0.0/16 network.
2. On the basis of the static interface route, R1 ARPs for the destination on `iface0`
3. R2 recognizes that it can reach the destination, and responds to the ARP with its own MAC.
4. R1 caches the ARP result that combines an IP in a remote network with the MAC of R2.

This happens for every distinct destination in 10.1.0.0/16. Consequently, even though the /16 is properly sub-netted beyond R2, and there are only two nodes on the link adjoining R1 and R2, R1 suffers ARP cache overload because it induces R2 to behave as if all 65k addresses are directly connected.

The reason I'm asking this question is because I hope it will help me make sense of the network service trouble reports (days later) that led us, eventually, to the overflowing ARP cache. In the spirit of the StackExchange model, I tried to distill that to what I believe is a crisp, specific question that can be answered objectively.

**EDIT 1** To be clear, I am asking about part of the glue layer between data link (layer 2) and network (layer 3), not the MAC forwarding table within the data link layer. A host or router builds the former to map IP addresses to MAC addresses, while a switch builds the latter to map MAC addresses to ports.

**EDIT 2** While I appreciate the effort to which responders have gone to explain why some implementations are not subject to ARP cache overflow, I feel that it is important for this question to address those that are. The question is "what happens when", not "is vendor *X* susceptible to". I've done my part now by describing a concrete example.

**EDIT 3** Another question this is not is "how do I prevent the ARP cache from overflowing?"

Comment: are you looking for information about the mac-address table or ARP table overflowing?

Comment: could you please elaborate on how you think the arp table would overflow?  is this related to a real problem, or purely hypothetical?  either way, we need details on what precise scenario we are respondding to

Comment: @MikePennington This is a real problem. The ARP cache could overflow if, for example, a large number of IPs are, or act as if they are, present on a single link.

Comment: Cisco IOS does not cache ARPs on a router unless the ARP is sourced from a subnet configured on the router.  When I say a "real problem", I mean a problem you're having... not a problem you're imaging could happen

Comment: Thanks for rewording the question because when I think of switches (layer 2) you have no ARP table. ARP has to do with TCP/IP and a layer 2 switch doesn't do any think like that, but when you get into layer three switching you may have a ARP table. However, if I remember correctly the interface on the layer 3 switch has to have an IP address to show up in the ARP table. Didn't really understand what you were saying at first, guest the early morning are being rough on me. The programmer in me thinks that once the ARP table is full it will either crash, overwrite, or drop any new ARP entries pro

Comment: Please see my update... I don't understand why you're not using a numerical next-hop address now that you see the error of your ways...

Comment: @MikePennington We switched to using a numerical next-hop after learning about the ARP cache overflow problem. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit 2**:

As you mentioned...

```
ip route 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 iface0
```

Forces the Brocade to proxy-arp for every destination in 10.1.0.0/16 as if it was directly connected to `iface0`.

I can't respond about Brocade's ARP cache implementation, but I would simply point out the easy solution to your problem... configure your route differently:

```
ip route 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 CiscoNextHopIP
```

By doing this, you prevent the Brocade from ARP-ing for all of 10.1.0.0/16 (note, you might need to renumber the link between R1 and R2 to be outside 10.1.0.0/16, depending on Brocade's implementation of things).

---

**Original answer**:

> I expect that in most, or even all, implementations, there is a hard limit on the capacity of the ARP table.

Cisco IOS CPU routers are only limited by the amount of DRAM in the router, but that is typically not going to be a limiting factor.  Some switches (like Catalyst 6500) have a hard limitation on the adjacency table (which is correlated to the ARP table); [Sup2T has 1 Million adjacencies](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps708/white_paper_c11-676346.html).

> So, what happens when the ARP cache is full and a packet is offered with a destination (or next-hop) that isn't cached?

Cisco IOS CPU routers don't run out of space in the ARP table, because those ARPs are stored in DRAM.  Let's assume you're talking about Sup2T.  Think of it like this, suppose you had a Cat6500 + Sup2T and you configured all Vlans possible, technically that is

```
4094 total Vlans - Vlan1002 - Vlan1003 - Vlan1004 - Vlan1005 = 4090 Vlans
```

Assume you make each Vlan a /24 (so that's 252 possible ARPs), and you pack every Vlan full... that is 1 Million ARP entries.

```
4094 * 252 = 1,030,680 ARP Entries
```

Every one of those ARPs would consume a certain amount of memory in the ARP table itself, plus the IOS adjacency table.  I dont know what it is, but let's say the total ARP overhead is 10 Bytes...

That means you have now consumed 10MB for ARP overhead; it still isn't very much space... if you were that low on memory, you would see something like `%SYS-2-MALLOCFAIL`.

With that many ARPs and a four hour ARP timeout, you would have to service almost 70 ARPs per second on average; it's more likely that the maintenance on 1 million ARP entries would drain the CPU of the router (potentially CPUHOG messages).

At this point, you could start bouncing routing protocol adjacencies and have IPs that are just unreachable because the router CPU was too busy to ARP for the IP.

Answer (score 2):

Only actual experience I had with this happening was on C3550 switches (2-8k MAC limit, depending on sdm template) and there it dropped the oldest entry from the table.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about the MAC forwarding table, not the ARP cache. Please see my edit.

Comment: I see your point. However, in this particular case, the effect was the same as these switches were also the L3 termination for a number of very large IP subnets. Eventually solved by replacing the switches. On L2 the switch floods frames it can't cache a MAC for but on L3 it has to drop older ARP entries and/or ARP for every packet which will quickly exhaust the CPU on those.

Answer (score 2):

For IOS and JunOS and other commercial stacks you just have to test, it's not very hard luckily.

But for [linux](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/core/neighbour.c), freebsd, netbsd, openbsd, uIP, lwIP and probably many other implementations you can just check their source code for the behavior.

In Linux you need to check 'net/core/neighbour.c' (start with line 'if (entries >= tbl->gc_thresh3' ||')  and 'net/ipv4/arp.c'.
In Linux you seem to have three full levels

1. gc_thresh1 - nothing is done until this is hit
2. gc_thresh2 - this can be hit momentarily
3. gc_thresh3 - this size cannot be exceeded

When gc_thresh3 tries to exceed, it tries to force garbage collection run, unless it has been already ran recently. Garbage collect appears to delete entries which are not referred to anymore, so does not mean oldest or newest, however gc_staletime exceeding seems to be one way of dereferencing entry, which again translates to oldest entry.
If garbage collect cannot be ran, new entry is simply not added. All these gc_threshN and periodic garbage collect intervals can be tuned.
The code is address family (ipv4, ipv6) agnostic, so IPv6 ND and IPv4 ARP tables are handled by exact same code-path, not duplicate path.

Answer (score 1):

It would arp for the IP address store it in the table and depending on implementation should delete the oldest entry. Impact to performance depends, if this is a uncommon occurance not much impact, but this is an attack vector so someone can send a lot of arps impacting processor utilization

Answer (score 1):

The switch is going to ARP for that destination IP to get it's MAC address (which would also populate the CAM table with the response).  The ARP request is broadcast to all ports.  This requires the CPU and involves the `ARP Input` process.  If the ARP requests are for the same IP, due to the ARP table overflowing frequently, the switch should rate-limit the ARP to once every two seconds.  If the requests are to random IPs frequently enough, CPU may spike as that CPU is involved in both the ARP requests and responses.

Comment: Where did you find the "once every two seconds" limit?

Comment: "ARP requests for the same IP address are rate-limited to one request every two seconds" -- http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps359/products_tech_note09186a00801c2af6.shtml#arp

Comment: Isn't it a C7500 specific value? For instance C6500 can use the "mls qos protocol arp police <bps>" command or CoPP.

Answer (score 1):

From the attacks I learned on Cisco 3550, 3560 etc. switches you can turn them into giant hub once you overload the MAC address limit. The switches have a set limit of MAC address (around 6000) that can be stored, and once that limit is reached it will flood all data out its interfaces. Can't remember if that goes for 802.1q packets because I have not had to do it in a long time. May have to fire up my network lab at home to find out.

Comment: It sounds like you are also talking about the MAC forwarding table, not the ARP cache. Please see my edit.